# (Quadratic?) Interpolation of data to find sector crossing time

Tags: interpolation

I am receiving data from a moving vehicle (race car in a game) at a rate of 60 times per second. I want to determine (as exact as possible) the time at which the vehicle crosses some sector (at some specified target distance along the track). Due to the limited update rate I will always receive one sample before the sector, and one sample after the sector, so I need to interpolate between those two points to find the time at which the sector was crossed (somewhere in between).

The data I receive each update contains:

- The time of that update `t`
- The position `p` along the track (in percentages 0-1)
- The velocity `v` of the vehicle

I am able to use simple linear interpolation using just the time and the distance, but it is not accurate enough. For example, if the sample before the crossing has time `t0` and position `p0`, and the sample after the crossing has `t1` and `p1`, and the crossing position is `p`, then the crossing time `t` from linear interpolation should be:

```
t = t0 + (p - p0) / (p1 - p0) * (t1 - t0)
```

This is relatively simple - it assumes a constant velocity of

```
v = (p1 - p0) / (t1 - t0)
```

and uses that to determine how long it should have taken to go from `p0` to `p`.

However, I don't want to assume constant velocity, I **have** the velocity on both samples and it is not equal.

How do I take into account the velocity that I have to make the interpolation more accurate? I am assuming I need to use some kind of quadratic interpolation instead of linear, where I'm assuming that the velocity changes linearly between the two samples (and therefore the time goes quadratically), but I fail to see how I should do this.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what CAN you assume of your system, you say you don't want to assume constant velocity, can you assume constant acceleration? at least within the timeframe, if neither, you can think it like a spline.

[image]

Basically what you have is two points, and its derivatives, the most you can get from it is a cubic interpolation without making any assumptions

From [Wikipedia Spline Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) the formulas are.

```
F(t0) = p0
F(t1) = p1
dF(t0)/dt = v0
dF(t1)/dt = v1

F(t) = (1-k)*p0 + k*p1 + k*(1-k)*(a*(1-k) + b*k)
where
k = (t-t0) / (t1-t0)
a = v0*(t1-t0) - (p1-p0)
b = -v1*(t1-t0) + (p1-p0)
```

Mind you, this will give you a cubic function `F(t)=p` and you will have to solve it to get the function `T(p)=t` that you want, and since we didn't assume anything, it is not guaranteed to be positive and increasing all the time, you could get very high accelerations, or negative velocities.